# How would I implement a file-based lookup table on Android?

Tags: android, file, search, seek

I am building an Android application, which loads a large dictionary into memory, such that remaining RAM is very limited.

I need to reference a second large word-list, but don't have the space to load it into RAM.

Since the "disk" on an Android device is actually also RAM, **would it be practical to quickly search my second list without first loading it into memory?**

I was thinking of some sort of disk-based divide-and-conquer algorithm.

For instance, I could format the 2nd list alphabetically with fixed-size fields,

- seek to the middle of the file, and grab that word
- determine if my word is in the first-half or second half
- recurse until I find my word (or don't)

But I don't know what the performance of doing it this way would be.  And I can't seem to find anything documented on the web about searching files this way.

Perhaps I am simply searching for the wrong terms.

**If anybody can point me to a tutorial on filesystem-based seeking in java (android) I would appreciate it!**

Comment: "Since the "disk" on an Android device is actually also RAM" -- no, it is not. "I was thinking of some sort of disk-based divide-and-conquer algorithm" -- is there any particular reason why you not using a database? Or at least an existing Java b-tree (or similar) library?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you implement a b-tree in the filesystem?  If so, any idea how?

Comment: Try searching the Web for `java btree database`. Personally, I would just use SQLite until I demonstrated that it would have insufficient performance.